# Execute a part of a stored procedure for only one report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have three reports(`a`,`b`,`c`) which have the same dataset `data` .
In this stored  procedure , I have a part which I want to be executed for only the report `a` 
I tried this but it didn't work

```
....
join  ReportServer.dbo.Catalog e
WHERE e.name = ''a''
```

Comment: Create a hidden parameter on all 3 reports and use an `if @param=1` type idea in the SP. pass 1 from report A and 0 from the others.

Comment: @DanielE. please post it as answer , awesome thanks .

Answer (score 3):

Create a hidden parameter on all 3 reports and use an if `@param=1` type idea in the SP. pass 1 from report A and 0 from the others.

Glad it worked out. :)